# How do I properly install Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, steam

Just as the title says. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, but I've used it before about a year ago. I had help then, but now this seems pretty confusing. I've already read the [Installing Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware) article, I'm currently trying to install Steam and when I do:

```
cd ~/downloads/
sudo dpkg steam_latest.deb
```

I get a error saying that I need python-apt and I tried doing

```
sudo apt-get python-apt
```

but it says *invalid operation* can you guys list the ways to install an application, and describe it like I'm five? Thanks.

**Edit: I'm not talking about using wine in this case, just using the actual package from Valve themselves.**

Comment: Programs like `dpkg`, `apt-get`, etc generally rely on arguments to specify the requested action. You can always use `man <program-name>` (e.g. `man dpkg`) to get more information about how they can be used properly.

Comment: Install steam directly from Ubuntu repo. There are some problems with the official, for example it opens every start a window with "please update steam" even when you the latest version

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You nearly had it correct, to install steam you need to add the `-i` flag to dpkg like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

And if that still fails you can install `python-apt` this way, which you as well had almost right:

```
sudo apt-get install python-apt
```

Comment: `sudo apt install` on current versions on Ubuntu.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you still can use both and will be able to use both untill EOL of 16.04 LTS which will be in 04/2021.

Comment: apt alone has a nifty progress bar though

Comment: @myol apt-get --show-progress

Comment: @Motte001 Really? `sudo apt-get --show-progress install 2048-qt` outputs something like `Avanzamento: [  0%]
Avanzamento: [ 16%]
Estrazione di 2048-qt (0.1.6-1)...
Avanzamento: [ 33%]
Avanzamento: [ 50%]
`. No progress bar, just more and more lines telling you the progress (sorry for the Italian btw). Using `sudo apt install 2048qt` produces an actual coloured progress bar using ncurses (I guess).

Comment: @Motte001 I think effort needed to type sudo apt-get --show-progress install is not worth the output. A rather easier approach is sudo apt install.

Answer (score 13):

As you are trying to install Steam, here is a different approach: Install Steam directly from Ubuntu's multiverse repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Reference: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Comment: This is by far the easiest option, as it will also automatically install dependencies (including python-apt) and updates, whereas the answer by Videonauth won't do so.

Comment: @PaddyLandau If you have a look at the [edit history of the question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/780663/revisions) itself you will see why my answer isn't satisfactory anymore. Its mostly because people edited the questions to something totally new.